# Can I control Intel's backlight when nvidia card is enabled?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, brightness, backlight

I am trying to control my screen's backlight using xbacklight.
I have intel HD graphics 530 (skylake) disabled, and nvidia gtx960M on.
(proprietary nvidia-361 driver active)

xbacklight has no effect when my nvidia card is enabled. And in fact, /sys/class/backlight only contains an intel_backlight folder (from which I can change brightness by modifying the value set in the "brightness" folder, even though intel card is disabled)

I tried different solutions found on other posts:
- kernel flags like acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor/native/... video.use_native_backlight=1, etc.
- Xorg conf file modification ("RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1")
- I also tried using redshift to control brightness, with no more success than xbacklight.

I would keep modifying brightness directly from the /sys/class/backlight/brightness file if I didn't experience issues with the saving of the value (which is comprised between 0 and 937..) which sometimes set brightness to 0 even though I specified normal values (like 500..).

Do you know if there is a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance for your answers =)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

I had Intel and NVidia cards and whenever I switch to NVidia's propriety driver `nvidia-381` using `nvidia-prime`, `xbacklight` didn't work.

Finally I have 2 solutions which allows changing brightness no matter which graphics card or driver you are using.

### 1st solution: Commandline solution

First, use this command to get max brightness:`/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-backlight-helper --get-max-brightness`. Say it gives value `y`.

Second, use this command to set brightness(requires `sudo`): `sudo /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-backlight-helper --set-brightness x`.

Replace `x` with any value between `0` to `y`.

I have tested it on `Ubuntu 14.04`. Might not work on `Kubuntu`.

**NOTES:**

1. Don't try to use `0` in `x`, you will get a blank screen aka screen with no brightness (Yes, you can type on blank screen in this case).
2. If you don't want to use `sudo` everytime in 2nd command then type `sudo visudo` and append `%VAR_USER ALL = NOPASSWD:
   /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-backlight-helper` to `sudoers`
   list. (Change `VAR_USER` to your username).

**Warning:** *Be careful when you edit `sudoers` list if you are not experienced user then don't do it.*

### 2nd solution: Graphical solution

Install `indicator-brightness` package using below commands(Please look at this answer for more elaborate steps):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:indicator-brightness/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-brightness
```

Add it to `startup applications` if you don't have its entry as shown below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

It is worth noting that `indicator-brightness` uses same commands found in  **1st solution** but as `daemon`.

> Also, **1st solution** can be used to set brightness on `virtual consoles` accessed via `Ctrl+Alt+F1` to `Ctrl+Alt+F6`.

Comment: Unfortunately i am on XFCE. Any suggestions?